# Inverted colour on output using Adobe Media Encoder

Tags: after-effects, adobe-media-encoder

I created an animation in AE, rendered it as a .MOV file, the video looks great, however the file size was huge and I saw that the recommended codec used to reduce file size is h.264 mp4. So i downloaded AME, and every time i render the video using it, whatever format i use, the video comes out with inverted colours.

How can I fix this?